# Php loop all result in next mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

i have a small problem. I use two mysql queries for getting data.
First i want to get IDs from groups

```
$sqlGoups = "SELECT * from `groups` WHERE `Date`='$TodayDate' ";
$result = $conn->query($sqlGoups);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $IDgroups = $row["ID"];
```

With that, I'll get those IDs, for example 5, 7, 12, 15, 22

I want to put them all in the next mysql query:

```
 $sqlNext = "SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE ID = '$IDgroups' ORDER BY `ID` ASC ";
$result = $conn->query($sqlNext);
```

When I do this, I get the result only for the first ID (5). And I want for each

I can not INNER JOIN tables because I use this in next query.

I tried with foreach loop, but no effect.

Comment: Why can't you just join and select the order fields? Like this: SELECT orders.* FROM orders 
JOIN groups on ( orders.ID = groups.ID )
WHERE groups.Date='$TodayDate' ORDER BY orders.ID ASC

Comment: I want to JOIN 3 tables - orders, groups and products, this is complicated

Comment: Why is that complicated? The performance impact for running multiple queries is much higher than crafting that one, single query once

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` 
WHERE ID  REGEXP CONCAT('(^|,)(', REPLACE('$IDgroups', ',', '|'), ')(,|$)') 
ORDER BY `ID` ASC
```

Comment: Please explain why that should be done - I've never seen such a complicated query for such a simple requirement

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Elanochecer commented the best bet should be a JOIN statement, but if you wish to go through your route, you could use the IN and provide the IDs as comma separated string, your query should look similar to the one below:

`...
$sqlNext = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE ID IN ('$IDgroups') ORDER BY ID ASC ";
...`

Also, confirm if $IDgroups is in the format 1,2,3,4

If you provide the schema I could come up with a workable JOIN statement for you, preferably you can create a repo with the schema

Comment: My code works fine, but only for first ID, they remained as if they did not exist

Comment: Have log from the while loop to confirm the first ID in question exist in the loop?